# Remove the UITableView Section Border and Background Color with Static Cells ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5

I am using `UITableView` with static cells to make a small form.

I added number of sections in the `UITableView` but now I have to remove the background color and the border of the section that displays the **Login** and **Forgot Password** button.

Check out the screenshot below.

[image]

## Question 1

How can I remove the background color and the border?

## Question 2

Also is there anyway to change the background color of the view. This view inherits from `UITableViewController`. I believe that I need to change the color of section or the group.

I assigned the identifier to the cell and got to remove the background color.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ButtonsCell"])
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



        NSLog(@"login buttons cells found");
    }


}
```

Here is the image:

[image]

But the borders are still showing!

---

## SOLUTION

Weird but works!

```
cell.backgroundView = nil;
```

Comment: Why dont you add those buttons inside tableview's footer view? for changing color, try to set backgroundColor property of self.

Comment: Can this be done using IB or I have to dive into code?

Comment: I haven't used IB, but it should be possible there. Check if you can drag and drop a UIView as table view's footer and then add buttons as its subviews.

Comment: I tried I don't think it can be done using IB.

Comment: @azamsharp you can add tablefooterview in interface builder itself. for that u need to add a prototype cell and create a separate view with two buttons and drag the view and drop below to the prototype cell will add that view as a footer view. then u can remove the unwanted prototype cell anyway..its easy..try it

Comment: I got everything to work but how do I change the color of the background of the tableView. I want to change the background from vertical lines to something else.

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as correct so it get's removed from the open questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do a switch cased based on your section within cellForRowAtIndexPath. Then replace the background of that row with a view that's transparent.

```
switch (section)
    {
        case BACKGROUND_SECTION:
        {
            // Only way I could find to get row centered
            segmentCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [segmentCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
            // Make the cell background transparent
            UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            segmentCell.backgroundView = backView;
        }
}
```