# IOS 7: Removing border from a section of grouped-style UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uitableview

After I moved to `iOS 7 / xcode 5`, the hidden `border` of the sections appeared although I handled this case for `iOS 6` and it worked for me.

In my code I'm using this to make the `section` border hidden, which works on `iOS 6` but not on `iOS 7`:

```
cell.backgroundView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

I tried all answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202965/removing-cell-borders-from-a-section-of-grouped-style-uitableview) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025645/remove-the-uitableview-section-border-and-background-color-with-static-cells) but no answer worked for me.

Please advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the separator between cells in a single section is the same as the border for the sections in IOS7. I solved my problem by setting the separator attribute of my table in  Interface Builder to None and drawing the separator lines manually for the sections that have more than one cell.

Answer (score 0):

What about implementing and playing with the header view:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Comment: what should I do with it if I want to remove the border of the section?

Comment: Try to create a white view and return it in that delegate, if it doesn't work then it means that this border doesn't come from the section:(.

Comment: Set the table separator to None instead of default solved the problem for me!  My question: is the separator the same as border for the grouped table in IOS7?

Comment: It seems yes since it is gone when you disable the separator.

Comment: OMG! then how can I keep the separator in the section that has multi cells? I need the separator between them in a certain section

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem myself.

In my case the section which I don't want section border has only one cell which is not data driven (in my case, a button). So I simply get rid of the section, and make a custom view to represent the content in that cell, then assign the custom view as the footer of the previous section.

It works for both iOS6/7 (of course) so I thought it would be good to put it here if anyone could use it.