# Removing/hidding a grouped table view cell's border in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, border, separator

I have a custom cell that contains an `UISegmentedControl`, and such cell is loaded in a grouped-style table view. Since in iOS 7 section separators have the table view's width, I need to hide or remove them. I've read this post dealing with this issue:

[IOS 7: Removing border from a section of grouped-style UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088574/ios-7-removing-border-from-a-section-of-grouped-style-uitableview)

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Thanks!